# MS Access 2010 maximum number of records

Tags: vba, microsoft-access-2010

I have VBA program written in Access 2010.  It creates and populates a table from a text file.  Previously, there have been less than 20,000 records total.  With the current data set, I get an overflow when it tries to add the 32,769th (32 K +1) record.  I have tried stopping it after it adds the 32,768th record and it works fine (without the overflow error).  Once I increase the max to 32,769, I get the overflow error.  Is there a maximum number of records that can be added via VBA?  I'm using the standard DAO calls - CreateDatabase, OpenDatabase, OpenRecordset, etc.  I'm copying existing tables from another db to create the tables.  Then a .AddNew, xxx = yyy ..., and .Update chain to add the records.  I'm using a Windows 7 64 bit OS.  Someone suggested using ADO instead of DAO, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.  It seems the first thing is to import or add a reference to System.Data.OleDb.dll.  Haven't been able to find that.  Any help would be appreciated.  I may end up re-writing the whole thing in C#.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more than likely that you are using a integer to specify the row. Try using a long instead. This should get you a little further before it dies.

Comment: They are longs.  I even split them up into multiple counters and using different ones when they reached a certain amount.  200,000, 23,300, 38,800.  All of which are fractions of the 2 Billion that is the largest long.

Comment: This is the limit of an integer indeed. If a long doesn't work, try a double. See also: http://cis.poly.edu/~mleung/CS394/f06/VBA/essentialElements/dataTypes.html. Also note, you have to specifically define them as long or VBA will switch between different types. so Dim MyVar as long will keep MyVar a long.

Comment: They are explicitly dim'ed as long.  I believe I even took the counters out at one point.  Just to eliminate them as a source of trouble.  I think that is how I determined that they weren't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doubles won't help longs should be fine. There must still be somewhere that is using an Integer if you are getting an overflow at 32769. Check your code carefully for Integers, Variants and undimmed veriables. Make sure you have Option Explicit at the top of all your modules as well because it might be that you have spelt a a variable name differently to where it is dimmed in which case it will be an Integer Variant not a Long if you start off with small numbers.

Comment: Option Explicit is at the top.  There 3 Integers in the program.  One is used for the return value and arguments of InStr().  The other 2 are file numbers for FreeFile.  4 Bytes, 3 Variants, 1 Boolean.  The rest are Strings, Databases, and Recordsets.

Comment: What are the varinants for?

Comment: What line of code actually fails, is it the Update statement? Could you copy and paste just the line where it fails on here?

Comment: That's a little difficult to do.  I probably IS the .Update call - the 32K'th one.

Comment: The Variant is to hold the result of a read from a text file

Comment: If you change the setting to Break On All Errors you'll be able to see the line where the error is happening and then hopefully see what variable is causing the problem.

Comment: The other 2 Variants are an array of 3 strings of length 1 and one of the values of the array

Comment: Well, being persistent about confirming which line was causing the overflow error paid off.  It was in another fn that read another value that was ultimately an Integer in a table.  Completely behind the scenes.  Anyway, I have to trace through to the program that uses this db to figure out exactly what to do.